# Would you approve this soldering job?

Tags: soldering, conductivity

I am new to soldering, and I am not sure if I did a good job while trying to solder some pins into a HX711. My concern is that the solder in SCK and VCC are touching (also E+ and E-), so I thought this might create some electrical noise, leading to mis-measurements.

[image]

Comment: Oh no. Cold solder, pads are not connected, short-circuit between pins.

Comment: you connected the pairs of header pins together, but you did not connect the headers to the board

Comment: i see some wire in the background ... cut two 10 cm pieces ... strip 5 cm of insulation from each of the pieces .... twist the bare ends .... touch the soldering iron to the very end of the wire ... wait for the wire to get hot .... touch the solder to the wire about 1 cm away from the soldering iron tip ... the solder should melt and soak into the twisted wires

Comment: There are great tutorials on youtube explaining how to solder. You should take a look, as you are not applying the iron correctly in ways that will be hard to understand in text but are very obvious when seen in video.

Comment: This feels like trolling. The language is too good for someone who can do THAT and then ask a question about it.

Comment: Would help to know what soldering iron you have, and what tip. The conical tips that most come with are useless.

Comment: Side note - to fix it, you would need a tool called "solder sucker" or "desoldering pump". Should cost about five bucks.

Comment: This ought to be trolling. In case it isn't... you need to actually see what a solder joint should look like before attempting to make one. You can't knit a sweater if you have never seen a sweater.

Comment: This almost serves as nightmare fuel - but it can be forgiven as it's your first time. You should watch some videos of soldering (not GreatScott) to get a gist and then practise. If you happen to have flux then that will make it much much easier to get a good joint. You want to heat the actual PCB pad itself *along with* the pin and then apply solder to the corner to connect both the pad and the pin.

Answer (score 22):

It could certainly serve as a bad example.

Heat applied to the wrong place, no flux, some combination of those. Fortunately there are plenty of [videos](https://youtu.be/b15MMzb_GWw) showing the right way to do it.

[image]

As long as you start with a nicely tinned soldering iron tip at some reasonable temperature and use good flux-core solder on fresh boards and parts you should never see anything like this.

Comment: Thanks Spehro, the image and video will certainly serve me. Best regards.

Answer (score 18):

I'm guessing how this solder-job went wrong...

- The soldering iron tip was applied to the rectangular pin, heating it sufficiently to melt solder.
- The soldering iron tip was **not applied** to the tinned printed-circuit board pad *at the same time*.

Since the pad received no heat, it didn't attract any solder. Both **pin** and **pad** must be heated by the soldering iron tip *at the same time*. After heating for a second-or-two, push solder into the area between pin and pad...rather than pushing solder into the soldering-iron-tip.
Solder containing flux should wick nicely into the space between pin and pad. Then pull the tip away from the joint.

Answer (score 11):

No, I wouldn't approve the job.  The grey frosted look of the two solders near your thumb are a pretty clear indication of a cold solder joint.  That could fail unpredictably, and Murphy's Law says at the worst possible moment.

The B+ node looks like it might be shorted to the B- node.  In general, there's too much solder at each joint, to the point where shorts are likely.  It also doesn't look like the plating on the through holes was heated at all.

As a rule, heat the *joint*, not the solder, and then touch the solder to a part of the joint you believe is hot, and not the iron tip.  If the solder melts, you're closer to doing it correctly than you are now.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the input. I really liked how you introduced me to Murphy's Law. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

No, those joints are not ok in their current form.

However it is likely easier to complete the remainder of the joints before going back and cleaning up the bad ones, getting a good solder joint while at the same time trying to stop a part falling out is much harder than doing the two jobs seperately.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single solder point on that image that isn't plain ridiculous, with far too much solder but none actually flowing on any solder pad.  You say "I am not sure if I did a good job".  That is really hard to believe since comparing with any circuit board should tell you how a sane solder joint looks, not with a ball of solder hanging in the air but with a (usually slightly concave) cone of solder covering the solder pad at its base and climbing up due to cohesion on the wire which forms an alloy at its surface with the solder, like the solder pad does.

Insufficient heating of the contact points leads to "cold" solder joints missing that alloying and not having reliable contact.  They can be hard to see when they are not as strikingly bad as on your picture.  So you may want to have someone help/teach you before improving your technique from producing obviously bad joints to hard to see bad joints.